# TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int

Tags: python, twitter, twint

I am trying to **scrape** for Tweets using Twint. The goal is to get tweets based on a keyword and print them according to the custom format provided by me. While setting up the twint configurations to **scrape** , I faced the following error

```
<ipython-input-19-dc1bb332d2a2> in <module>
      5 c.Limit = 1
      6 c.Pandas = True
----> 7 twint.run.Search(c)

14 frames
/content/twint/twint/format.py in Tweet(config, t)
     21         output = output.replace("{hashtags}", ",".join(t.hashtags))
     22         output = output.replace("{cashtags}", ",".join(t.cashtags))
---> 23         output = output.replace("{replies}", t.replies_count)
     24         output = output.replace("{retweets}", t.retweets_count)
     25         output = output.replace("{likes}", t.likes_count)

TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

The code I am trying is :

```
# Set up TWINT config
c = twint.Config()
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
c.Search = "football"
# Custom output format

c.Format = "Username: {username} |  Tweet: {tweet}"
c.Limit = 1
c.Pandas = True
twint.run.Search(c)
```

I checked the `format.py` and the replace() function config looks like this

```
def Tweet(config, t):
    if config.Format:
        logme.debug(__name__+':Tweet:Format')
        output = config.Format.replace("{id}", t.id_str)
        output = output.replace("{conversation_id}", t.conversation_id)
        output = output.replace("{date}", t.datestamp)
        output = output.replace("{time}", t.timestamp)
        output = output.replace("{user_id}", t.user_id_str)
        output = output.replace("{username}", t.username)
        output = output.replace("{name}", t.name)
        output = output.replace("{place}", t.place)
        output = output.replace("{timezone}", t.timezone)
        output = output.replace("{urls}", ",".join(t.urls))
        output = output.replace("{photos}", ",".join(t.photos))
        output = output.replace("{video}", str(t.video))
        output = output.replace("{thumbnail}", t.thumbnail)
        output = output.replace("{tweet}", t.tweet)
        output = output.replace("{language}", t.lang)
        output = output.replace("{hashtags}", ",".join(t.hashtags))
        output = output.replace("{cashtags}", ",".join(t.cashtags))
        output = output.replace("{replies}", t.replies_count)
        output = output.replace("{retweets}", t.retweets_count)
        output = output.replace("{likes}", t.likes_count)
        output = output.replace("{link}", t.link)
        output = output.replace("{is_retweet}", str(t.retweet))
        output = output.replace("{user_rt_id}", str(t.user_rt_id))
        output = output.replace("{quote_url}", t.quote_url)
        output = output.replace("{near}", t.near)
        output = output.replace("{geo}", t.geo)
        output = output.replace("{mentions}", ",".join(t.mentions))
        output = output.replace("{translate}", t.translate)
        output = output.replace("{trans_src}", t.trans_src)
        output = output.replace("{trans_dest}", t.trans_dest)
    else:
        logme.debug(__name__+':Tweet:notFormat')
        output = f"{t.id_str} {t.datestamp} {t.timestamp} {t.timezone}
```

If there is anything anyone could help me with that would be great. If the question needs to be rewritten, also please let me know, not very good at forming questions.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter needs to be a `str`, not an `int`.

Use this instead:

```py
output = output.replace("{replies}", str(t.replies_count))
```

Comment: Thank you but a new problem arose
`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found`
for this line of code
`output = output.replace("{mentions}", "," .join(t.mentions))`

Comment: Perhaps you could search stackoverflow to see if anyone has done that before.